# replacement of system() to run an .exe file which does not open cmd window in background

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, cmd

I am having visual studio 2005 and win 7 installed in my system. In c++ I am downloading an .exe from my local server using URLDownloadToFile(). After downloading I need to run this .exe file. I am able to do this using system("path to the .exe file") but it opens a cmd window in background. Can anybody tell me what other method can I use to replace system() which doesn't opens a cmd window in background.

I had also given try to following methods

```
 1. ShellExecute(NULL,(LPCWSTR) "explore",(LPCWSTR) "C:/Users/ay\\AppData/Roaming/path-here/file.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
 2.     LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Users\\ay\\AppData\\Roaming\\path-here\\file.exe -L -S"));
        CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

But none of these command  can start running my .exe file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the downloaded successfully then try the following solution.

```
CString exeFileName;
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), exeFileName.GetBuffer(), NULL, sExePresentInDirectory, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

exeFileName.ReleaseBuffer();
```

I have tried, It works fine.

For more help please refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).